# How many amperes can pass through drain-source of a FQPF9N50C if 3.3v are applied to gate-source?

Tags: mosfet, current, amperage

I a playing around with this N-channel mosfet I found at home ([FQPF9N50C](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/149/FQPF9N50C-111306.pdf)). Using this simple circuit:

[image]

I am able to turn on an off the 12v load using by connecting 3.3v to the mosfet. The load is a small motor, was the first 12v thing I found, the real application will use a 12v 20w lamp. And that triggered my question.

How can I know how many amperes can pass through the mosfet when using 3.3v to switch?

*Im clearly not very experiences on this field, just doing this for a hobby project. Tried reading the datasheed but I find it a bit hard to understand.*

Comment: "the real application will use a 12v 20w lamp" - if it's an incandescent lamp then you have another problem - cold resistance of the filament is about 10 times smaller than during normal operation, so it will try to draw ~17A. If the MOSFET can't deliver this current the lamp filament won't get hot so its resistance won't increase and the MOSFET will quickly overheat with almost 12V across it. Your FET should be rated for _at least_ 17A, as well as being able to pass this current with minimal voltage drop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A FET is controlled by the gate voltage, Vgs (Voltage gate-source). The datasheet always contains these graphs explaining the relation of Vgs to drain current, Id.

[image: FQPF9N50C Figure 2. Transfer Characteristics]
With 3.3 Vgs it conducts nothing at 25C if you must believe the Vgs/Id graph.

[image: FQPF9N50C Figure 1. On-Region Characteristics]
But, this FET can do 1A@12V at 4.5V Vgs according to the lowest line in this graph.

You need at least 5 Vgs to switch this FET, all other specifications in the datasheet use 10 Vgs, so that would be the recommended value.

In short: you need more then 3.3V to switch this FET. If you do not have more, acquire a logic level FET. (eg: FDP5800)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Could you let me know how do you get 1A@12V from the graph when the axis say 10-1 - 100 - 101?

Comment: @Mark It's a logarithmic graph. 10^-1 is 0.1 then 10^0 is 1 and 10^1 is 10.